# How can I reinitialize an already loaded bootstrap table?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `table table-bordered table-hover table-stripped` table loaded with some data.
I reload the rows with ajax and the table becomes ugly, losing all the properties of the table-bordered, table-hover and table-stripped bootstrap classes.
How can I reload those properties? Does it come with the JS?

Edit:
Here's the code.

Table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-stripped" id="data_list">
    <tr>
        <th>Lot</th>
        <th>size</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($lots as $lot): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $lot['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $lot['size']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

JS:

```
...
$.ajax({type: "POST",cache: false,url: '?', dataType: "html", data: submitdata,
    success: function(res) {
        $('#data_list').html(res);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        bootbox.alert("There was an error, try again. "+thrownError);
    },
    async: true
});
```

AJAX response:

```
<tr>
    <th>Lot</th>
    <th>Size</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>38706000524</td>
    <td>30</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: how are you "reloading" the table? can you provide your code please

Comment: there you go. Thank you

Comment: are you returning the correct internal html for a table from your server? what is the data in `res`?

Comment: I reload the inner html of the table with some simple data, just the rows with cells inside. but the new rows look ugly and don't have the hover effect

Comment: the data in res is 

    <tr>
     <th>Lot</th>
     <th>Size</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>38706000524</td>
     <td>30</td>
    </tr>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `table` element requires a `tbody` wrapper for its internals. On most browsers, if you dont explicitly define one, it will automatically wrap one around the internals for you.

If you inspect your page's generated code, you'll notice there is a `tbody` present that you didnt specify in your original html.

When you're replacing the contents using `.html()` the browser doesnt perform the automatic wrapping, so you lose the `tbody`.

You should either return one as part of your server code AND update your original code.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-stripped" id="data_list">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Lot</th>
            <th>size</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($lots as $lot): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $lot['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $lot['size']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

OR add one in your original code, and change the `.html()` replace code to be

```
 $('#data_list tbody').html(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could figure it up. When the table is loaded, bootstrap adds the

```
<tbody>
```

container. If you modify the table later, you must not overwrite that element.

I changed my ajax response from

```
<tr>
    <th>Lot</th>
    <th>Size</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>38706000524</td>
    <td>30</td>
</tr>
```

to

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Lot</th>
        <th>Size</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>38706000524</td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```